# How to merge perl Net::LDAP search objects?

Tags: perl, netldap

I have a task where I need to compare some employee IDs in a DB with the official source of current employee IDs that lives in an LDAP DB.

So I have a list of 3700 company IDs, which are called uid in the LDAP schema.

I realised that it might not be A Good Thing to just create a huge query like

```
(|(uid=foo1)(uid2=foo2)....(uid=foo3700))
```

and submit it. So I came up with the idea of chopping my list into chunks. I did some timing and for chunks of 50 the query ran in 7 minutes, 100 in 4 minutes and 200 in 3.5 minutes.

But now I have several search objects, one per query.

I imagine I can

1. loop over the chunks and query and process the objects and store the results for reporting later. Or I can
2. store the search results in some sort of array or hash. Or I can
3. somehow combine the search results into a big search object.

I kind of like the idea of 3., because it strikes me as the most generic solution, but I have no idea how to do it.

So is 3. a good approach?

If so, how to do it?

Otherwise, what are better approaches to this problem?

Comment: Just to make sure you checked first, are you sure these uids do not belong to any group or ou? The fact that you have to retrieve them one by one sounds strange to me.

Comment: I don't know in advance if they all belong to some group or ou.